# Python: Двоечные последовательности

Tags: python

**Условие:** 
Вводится число N. Сгенерируйте в лексикографическом порядке все последовательности длины N, состоящие из чисел 2, 4, 5, в которых количество двоек не превосходит 2-х.

В "лексикографическом порядке" обозначает, что если на первых X местах две последовательности совпадают, а на месте X+1 - различаются, то раньше должна идти та из них, в которой число на месте X+1 меньше.

1<=N<=10

Формат ввода

```
3
```

Формат вывода

```
2 2 4
2 2 5 
2 4 2 
2 4 4 
2 4 5 
2 5 2 
2 5 4 
2 5 5 
4 2 2 
4 2 4 
4 2 5 
4 4 2 
4 4 4 
4 4 5 
4 5 2 
4 5 4 
4 5 5 
5 2 2 
5 2 4 
5 2 5 
5 4 2 
5 4 4 
5 4 5 
5 5 2 
5 5 4 
5 5 5
```

Проблема заключается в том, что Яндекс.Контест ругается на то, что ответ неверный. В чем дело? Мой код указан ниже.

```
from itertools import product
i = open('input.txt', 'r')
o = open('output.txt', 'w+')
l = int(i.read())
ALPHA = "245"
d = []
for s in product(ALPHA, repeat=l):
    d.append([" ".join(s)])
for q in d[1:]:
    s = " ".join(q)
    if int(s.count('2')) > 2:
        continue
    o.write(" ".join(q) + '\n')
i.close()
o.close()
```

Comment: А что именно не нравится контесту не известно? навскидку, единственное отличие выходного файла от примера - последняя пустая строка.

Comment: В том то и проблема, что лог компилятора пустой. Что за пустая строка?

Comment: Пустая строка (перевод каретки) в конце вашего файла output.txt